# DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode in Avalonia UI?

Tags: c#, .net, avaloniaui

In WPF, you can detect whether it is showing in design mode using

```
DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode
```

What's the equivalent in Avalonia UI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Avalonia the equivalent is `Avalonia.Controls.Design.IsDesignMode`